# Firebase Rule for value of the first child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How can I write a Firebase rule that refers to the value of the first (and only, if that helps) child of the new data? For example: 
**Data**

```
{
    "aaa": "bbb"
}
```

**Rule**

```
".write": "newData.children[0].val() === auth.uid"
```

This doesn't work, apparently. What would be a correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the Firebase RTDB security rules are compiled for performance reasons. This style of dynamic references wouldn't work. There is no concept of `length` but instead just exists, does not exist, and the current and new values.

Let's say you have the following data:

```
"path/to/data": {
  "aaa": "bbb"
}
```

While there is no way in security rules for the RTDB to limit the number of children (on it's own), you can instead go one level deeper to apply the restriction you desire.

```
"path": {
  "to": {
    "data": {
      "$anyValue": {
        ".write": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```